# Typescript decorator passing as parameter - Developing dynamic nestjs provider

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm learning Nestjs - TypeORM,
below is code for provider

```
export const RoleProvider = [{
    provide: 'ROLE_PROVIDER',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.getRepository(RoleEntity),
    inject: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION']
}
]
```

Now, I'm trying to develop this provider as dynamic by implementing decorator

```
export const PrepareProviderName = (target: Object) => {
    console.log('prepare provideer name', target, target['databaseProvider']);
    var original = target['entity'];
    console.log('>',typeof target['entity']);
    return [
        {
            provide: target['name'],
            useFactory: async (conn: Connection) => await conn.getRepository(original.prototype),
            inject: target['dataseProvider']
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is the decorator

Below is entity - module code

```
@Entity({ name: 'roles' })
export class RoleEntity extends SowBaseEntity {


    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    Name: string;
}


@Module({
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers:
        [...databaseProvider,
        ...PrepareProviderName(
            {
                name: "ROLE_PROVIDER",
                databaseProvider: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'],
                entity: RoleEntity
            }
        ),
            RoleProfile,
            UserService,
            AppLogger]
})
export class RoleModule { }
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'roles' })
export class RoleEntity extends SowBaseEntity {


    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    Name: string;
}
```

Now I'm facing error/blocker that I'm not able pass entity as-is to the repository.
Could any one help in fixing it